# Update value in Cassandra DB

Tags: cassandra

I have a cassandra db and i want to update all the columns in table.

But the column is set

Example :

```
Table1

Id  value
1    ab
2    ab,cd
3    cd

Now, I want to change all "ab" to "abc".
```

I know the normal update command wont work here, is there a way to achieve this ?

```
update table1 set value =abc where value =ab // This wont work.
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of is:

1. Use application logic to get all of the ids into a list or array
2. Iterate over that list, and use LWT(Light Weight Transaction) like this.

> update test set name='abc' where id=ID_FROM_LIST if name='ab';

Comment: Can you explain me more in this ? Is there a way to store all ids in Cassandra DB itself ?

Comment: No nested queries are not possible in CQL/Cassandra. You have to use application side logic (Java, Scala or Python etc.) to do this

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me the typical unfortunate situation: a (very) bad design. You should not try to use C* as a relational database. Everything will fail on you as soon as you start modeling something, and this is a typical example of what NOT to do with C*.

I see this in two ways:

1. You don't own data and you're starting from scratch. I'd suggest you to find *another* way to represent your data, especially NOT in the form of ID/value pairs.
2. You own the data, and you need to put them in a database. I'd suggest you to go the relational way by changing database system and perform that transformations there.

However, there's a third case:

3. You insist on C* because you inherited both model and data on a C* database.

In that case, the best way to perform what you're trying to do is to do things in the C* way: **you have to denormalize your data to satisfy your needs**. That means creating a new table that will allow you to perform the *reverse* lookup. Something along these lines should be enough:

```
CREATE TABLE reverse_table (
    value text,
    id int,
    PRIMARY KEY (value, id)
);
```

Now, assuming you need to perform these transformations multiple times, the next step is to populate that table by reading **all** the records from your main table. Once this table has been populated you have an *updated* model that could be used to perform what you want.

Warning: you **must** keep these two tables in sync.

With this model, the equivalent of yours

> update table1 set value =abc where value =ab // This wont work.

is

```
SELECT id FROM reverse_table WHERE value = 'ab';
```

and then for each id returned perform with something like:

```
**1.**  UPDATE table SET value = 'abc' WHERE id = id_from_the_query_above
**2.**  DELETE FROM reverse_table WHERE value = 'ab' AND id = id_from_the_query_above;
**3.**  INSERT INTO reverse_table (value, id) VALUES ('abc', id_from_the_query_above);
```

where with **1.** you change the main table, with **2.** you *unhook* your 'ab'/id record from the reverse table, and with **3.** you *hook* your new 'abc'/id pair. You may also want to perform these three queries in a BATCH statement instead of async queries to force these tables in sync.

All of this seems **veeeeery** inefficient to me...

Answer (score 0):

-- Fetch the row(s) that contain the value "ab"

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE value CONTAINS 'ab';
```

After executing the above query, you will get the rows that contain the value "ab". Then, you need to modify the values in those rows to replace "ab" with "abc". In this case, you have three rows that contain the value "ab" (row with Id 1, 2, and 3).

-- Update the rows by replacing "ab" with "abc"

```
UPDATE your_table SET value = 'abc' WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE your_table SET value = 'abc,cd' WHERE id = 2;
UPDATE your_table SET value = 'cd' WHERE id = 3;
```

or you can use below

`UPDATE Table1 SET value = REPLACE(value, 'ab', 'abc');`